# What does (stage=0) mean in Veins application?

Tags: omnet++, veins

I've been studying TraciDemo11p and couldn't clearly understand what does stage means.

```
void TraCIDemo11p::initialize(int stage)
{
    DemoBaseApplLayer::initialize(stage);
    if (stage == 0) {
        sentMessage = false;
        lastDroveAt = simTime();
        currentSubscribedServiceId = -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is explained in the [OMNeT++ user manual, section 4.3.3.3 ("Multi-Stage Initialization")](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:simple-modules:multi-stage-init): Basically, OMNeT++ modules can be initialized in multiple stages. This allows modules to ensure that, first, all stage 0 initialization is performed for all modules, then all stage 1 initialization, and so on.

Comment: Init stage 0 is usually used to set up variables, allocate memory etc.